# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in webservice code

Tags: ios, web-services, swift

I have binded my **login action** and tried to call restfull **webservice**.
[image]

Below is my code:

```
 @IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    println(emailTextField.text)
    println(pwdTextField.text)

  let plainData = emailTextField.text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
  println(base64String)

    let plainDataPwd = pwdTextField.text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64StringPwd = plainDataPwd?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
    println(base64StringPwd)

   var urlPath = "http://inspect.dev.cbre.eu/SyncServices/api/jobmanagement/PlusContactAuthentication?email=\(base64String)&userPwd=\(base64StringPwd)"

     var url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: urlPath)
     var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection! = NSURLConnection(request: request,
        delegate: self,startImmediately: false)
     connection.start()
}
```

I found nil while unwrapping optional value in webservice

Comment: In which line does the error happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
  @IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {

    println(txt1.text)
    println(txt2.text)
    let base64String : NSString = ""
    let base64StringPwd : NSString = ""

    if let plainData = txt1.text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){

    let base64String = plainData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
    println(base64String)

    }

    if  let plainDataPwd = txt2.text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){
    let base64StringPwd = plainDataPwd.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
    println(base64StringPwd)

    }

    var urlPath : NSString? = "http://inspect.dev.cbre.eu/SyncServices/api/jobmanagement/PlusContactAuthentication?email=\(base64String)&userPwd=\(base64StringPwd)"

    var url = NSURL(string: urlPath!)
    if let url1 = url{

        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url1)
        var connection: NSURLConnection! = NSURLConnection(request: request,
            delegate: self,startImmediately: false)
        connection.start()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: hi Dharmesh. thanks for the help..this is perfect..it resolved my issue.But somehow i cant access the web service call now..Can u tell me how can i set json as a param and send?

Comment: sorry to bothering you again dharmesh. i have edited my updated code with param and content type...is it fine?and where do i add shared session.Can you please help me little more in this.I am stuck with this since 2 days.

Comment: thanks dharmesh ..your previous solution works for me...but i got to do the GET method.now i am checking that how to get the resonse from this method?

Answer (score 1):

Use **TouchUpInside** instead of **TouchDown**.
Probably your method is getting called multiple times.

Comment: But this is not an answer.